# JavaScript Conditional Comments for IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Here is the classic **conditional comment** to target Internet Explorer 9+ and all non-IE browsers:

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
    IE 9+ and all non-IE browsers see this text.
<!--<![endif]-->
```

What is the purpose of each of the 4 parts?

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]>
<!-->
<!--
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are HTML comments with conditional statements and operators. Let me break it down:

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
```

The `gt` here means 'greater than, and `IE` means Internet Explored, and the version right behind. This:

```
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Means to end the conditional statement. This particular syntax differs from the regular HTML compatible syntax:

```
<!--[if condition]>-->
   Stuff here
<!--<![endif]-->
```

due to the following reason, from [SitePoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/internet-explorer-conditional-comments/):

> IE7 and later browsers will also reveal the `-–>` after the opening conditional statement. The fix suggested by Microsoft is to add an extra `<!` just after the opening conditional comment.

This means the `-->` after `<!--[if condition]>` is being interpreter by IE 7+ browsers. The comments you've given are used to combat this. Read more about conditional comments [at Microsoft's MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If a browser get confused about how to parse the **if**, then this looks like a plain old html comment:

```
<!--  [if gt IE 8]><!  -->
```

and so does this:

```
<!--  <![endif]  -->
```